# Is this statement about lust true in Hinduism?

Tags: belief, manu-smriti, sex, parents, mother

> 2.215. One should not sit in a lonely place with one’s mother, sister, or daughter; for the senses are powerful, and master even a learned man.

I'm not a Hindu, but is the belief really that a son and his mother can't be in the same room because of lust?

(I'm really here for learning not to criticize hinduism but this seems very nauseating, so if this is wrong please correct me)

Comment: This verse is from Manu Smriti (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199691.html) .. It just emphasizes the power of lust which can delude even saints of the highest order .. it does not imply anything else.

Comment: It is important to note that *Manusmiriti* is a *smriti*, which means it is NOT meant to be taken literally. If you sit alone with your mother, sister, or even daughter then it does NOT imply a sin, in contrast to *Shrutis* which at times needs to be taken more literally.